# How do I prevent render from HTML encoding data in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

In my controller I wish to return HTML inside a json response, which will then be inserted via jQuery inside a div, using .html().

my controller :

```
div_content = view_context.link_to "logout", logout_path, method: :delete + '<div class="
return render :json => {:success => true, :username => current_user.email, :div_content =>  div_content}
```

javascript :

```
$('#special_div').html(data.div_content)
```

This content is html encoded and so the HTML does not render.  I know that I can convert the string using regular expressions or something, on the javascript side but it seems to make sense to not send it encoded from the server.

Comment: can you try passing `div_content` to `raw`?  `view_context.raw(div_content)` or just use `div_content.html_safe`.  I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: I had tried the view_context.raw, that did not work.  I just tried html_safe, which did not work.  Wouldn't html_safe convert things into html entity codes?

Comment: I would construct the html client-side in JavaScript with JSON variables rather than mixing html with json...

Comment: I would have gone that route, but I needed to use the helper functions for creating links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the more correct solution is to render a partial, which contains all the logic and formatting needed.  This makes much more sense since in the partial you can use your template engine and such.